# Get different object from Ninject depending on ConstructorArgument

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

I have following code:

```
kernel.Get<IFoo>(new ConstructorArgument("rule", myRule))
```

I want that I get different objects depending of the value in myRule. How do I do that?
Something like this psedocode

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo1>().When(x=>x.Parameters[0].Value.Type=="type1")
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo2>().When(x=>x.Parameters[0].Value.Type=="type2")
```

where Type is a member of myRule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the type of constructor arguments is not easily possible. You might want to change to using either Named bindings or metadata and constraints instead.

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo1>().WithMetadata("Type", typeof(MyRule1))
kernel.Get<IFoo>(m => m.Get<Type>("Type", null) == typeof(myRule), ConstructorArgument("rule", myRule))
```

But remind to access the kernel only from the configuration (e.g. factories belonging to the configuration)